# How to get nested list values using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

When i click on fold2.1 i need to get values "fold2.1" and "fold2" and also when i click on "doc 6" i need to get "doc6" , "fold2.1" and "fold2" values.

same as "fold2.2" i need to get values "fol2.2" and "fold2" and also when i click on chld "Doc 7" i need to get "Doc 7 " , "fol 2.2" and "fol2" values.

**HTML File:**

```
<li class="favdelParentFold">
  <a href="#parentLevel1" data-toggle="collapse" class="" aria-expanded="true">
    <span class="caret-right"></span>
  </a><span class="folder"></span><span id="pfDel">fold2</span><span data-toggle="modal" data-target="#AddFavorites_ModalDel" class="trashcan"> press me</span>
  <ul class="collapse in" id="parentLevel1" aria-expanded="true">

    <li class="favorite"><a id="pfDocDel" href="">one 1</a><span data-toggle="modal" data-target="#AddFavorites_ModalDel" class="trashcan">press me</span></li>
    <li class="favorite"><a id="pfDocDel" href="">one 2</a><span data-toggle="modal" data-target="#AddFavorites_ModalDel" class="trashcan">press me</span></li>
    <li class="favorite"><a id="pfDocDel" href="">one 3</a><span data-toggle="modal" data-target="#AddFavorites_ModalDel" class="trashcan">press me</span></li>
    <!-- ROOT DOCS -->

    <li class="favdelSubFold">
      <a href="#1childlevel1" data-toggle="collapse">
        <span class="caret-right"></span></a><span class="folder">
                                                                    </span><span id="sfDel">fold2.1</span><span data-toggle="modal" data-target="#AddFavorites_ModalDel" class="trashcan">press me</span>
      <ul id="1childlevel1" class="collapse in">

        <li class="favorite">
          <a id="sfDocDel" href="https://www.cna.com" target="_blank">doc6</a><span data-toggle="modal" data-target="#AddFavorites_ModalDel" class="trashcan">press me</span></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="favdelSubFold">
      <a href="#1childlevel2" data-toggle="collapse">
        <span class="caret-right"></span></a><span class="folder">
                                                                    </span><span id="sfDel">fold2.2</span><span data-toggle="modal" data-target="#AddFavorites_ModalDel" class="trashcan">press me</span>

      <ul id="1childlevel2" class="collapse in">

        <li class="favorite">
          <a id="sfDocDel" href="https://www.cna.com" target="_blank">doc7</a><span data-toggle="modal" data-target="#AddFavorites_ModalDel" class="trashcan">press me</span></li>

      </ul>

    </li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

**JS Script**

```
$(".favdelParentFold ul li .trashcan").click(function() {
  if ($(this).parent().find('ul').length || $(this).closest('.favdelSubFold').length <1 ) return;

  var tr = $(this).prev('a').text();
  var pa = $(this).closest('.favdelParentFold').find('#pfDel').text();
  var ya = $(this).parent('#sfDocDel').text();
  alert(tr);
  alert(pa);
  alert(ya);
});
```

Working Code:

https://jsfiddle.net/atg5m6ym/409/

Comment: You cannot have duplicate IDs on a page. That is invalid HTML and the browser can only access the first match. Use a class for the `id=pfDel` values.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have duplicate IDs on a page. That is invalid HTML and the browser can only access the first match. Use a class for the `id=pfDel` values (and for anything else that has IDs that are not unique per element).

A few lines of your code then changes to use a class selector for `pfDel` etc:

```
  var tr = $(this).prev('a').text();
  var ya = $(this).closest('.favdelSubFold').find('.sfDel').text();
  var pa = $(this).closest('.favdelParentFold').find('.pfDel').text();
```

**Corrected sample:** https://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/atg5m6ym/413

Comment: :When i click on fold2.1 i need to get values "fold2.1" and "fold2" and also when i click on "doc 6" i need to get "doc6" , "fold2.1" and "fold2" values.

Comment: @GobinathMahalingam: I am still trying to remove all the duplicate IDs in your page. You have them everywhere and they simply will not work. Keep checking the answer for updates to the link.

Comment: @GobinathMahalingam: You need to explain the overall aim as the code makes little sense in isolation. I can't format the HTML as JSFiddle appears broken today, but I have it generating the values you wanted based on the tree as I interpret it. Variable names like `ya` and `pa` mean nothing to me.